# Why htaccess file not working at subfolder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, backend

I am currently having a problem with .htaccess on the subfolder.
I have a .htcaccess file in the folder root/chartService:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /obesity-visualizer/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^chart/([^/]+)/?$ /chartService/index.php?bmi=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^chart/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /chartService/index.php?bmi=$1&year=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have another model file line.php in folder root/app/models:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['bmi'])) {
    $url = 'http://localhost/obesity-visualizer/chart/' . $_GET['bmi'];

    // Create a new cURL resource
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $res = curl_exec($c);
    $error = curl_error($c);
    $errno = curl_errno($c);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);

    if ($errno !== 0) {
        // cURL error occurred  
        header("Location: /obesity-visualizer/app/controllers/admin/countries.php");
        exit;
    }

    $data = json_decode($res, true);
    echo $data;
} else {
    // BMI not specified
    header("Location: /obesity-visualizer/app/controllers/admin/countries.php");
    exit;
}
```

I want this cURL to access the .htaccess I created in the chartService folder and do the relevant rewrite. .htaccess does not work in the subfiles.

The ReWrite module is turned on in the Apache config file. I also set the "AllowOverride All" option. It works fine when I run the same .htaccess file in the root folder, but not when I put it into a subfolder. This is the only .htaccess file so it does not conflict with any other.

Comment: Your first `RewriteRule` is rewriting to `/chartService/index.php`, whereas the second is to `/obesity-visualizer/chartService/index.php` - is that correct? (It doesn't _look_ correct.) (The `RewriteBase` directive is not being applied here.)

Comment: I edited it. Problem still occurs.

Comment: What is your web root folder here? Is `obesity-visualizer` supposed to be an actually existing directory, and if not, where are you doing the rewriting that handles this?

Comment: The `.htaccess` is in `/chartService/` and looking for URLs starting with `/obesity-visualizer/chart/`. That's why it's not working, as the `.htaccess` is never accessed for URLs going to `/obesity-visualizer/chart/`. You'd need this file to be in the root directory or `/obesity-visualizer/`